# change php page url using htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess

I want to change the url from

```
http://mywebsite/address.php?state=oh&office_id=1425
```

to

```
http://mywebsite/office/{variable inside my php page}.php
```

appreciate if you can help me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^office/([0-9]+).php$ address.php?state=oh&office_id=$1
```

Which would result in:

```
http://expample.com/office/1425.php
```

Or if you'd like the state to be dynamic as well, you could do this:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^office/([a-zA-Z]+)/([0-9]+).php$ address.php?state=$1&office_id=$2
```

Which would result in:

```
http://expample.com/office/oh/1425.php
```

Comment: Thanks Josh, my php variable is the office name (one word), how htaccess will show this?

Comment: +1 for the answer. Just I think the state must also be part of the URL and passed as param to the script.

Comment: Updated, hopefully it's better worded now.

Comment: Many thanks for you all, if I passed the statename to the url, what is the final htaccess line should I use

Comment: @Pipo You'd use the second one if you wanted the GET variable of state to be dynamic.

Comment: I made the link http://my website/address.php?state=oh&office_id=1422&l_name=BOWLING%20GREEN and used RewriteRule ^office/([a-zA-Z]+).php$ address.php?state=$1&office_id=$2&l_name=$3 but it's not working, appreciate if you can help

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to have a look at **mod_rewrite** Apache module.
You can do various URL manipulations with it.

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html

Beginner's guide:

http://www.workingwith.me.uk/articles/scripting/mod_rewrite